# Linux user creation with php

Tags: php, ubuntu

I am trying to write a php script to create users for my email server, however I am having an issue with the rights of the php intereter. The lines i am try to execute are as follows:

```
useradd -m -s /usr/sbin/nologin username
```

and then `user:pass | chpasswd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see this same issue come up quite frequently. Apache runs as `www-data:www-data` on ubuntu. When you perform `exec('useradd -m -s /usr/sbin/nologin username')`, it will execute with the same permissions as `www-data` has, not as a `sudoer` in the command line.

You need to adjust the permissions, fix the relationship, or offload it to a Cron Task that `can` execute with the correct permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I thought it was an issue with privledges.

Answer (score 1):

Script on Linux is actually executed by apache itself. Apache’s user `www-data` needs to be granted privileges to execute certain applications using `sudo`.

There are ways to achive this,

You want to edit /etc/sudoers and using `sudo visudo` this can be done.

`www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/useradd, usr/bin/php`

Assuming that you want to run `useradd` and `php` using root privileges.